# Pagination of Tumblr Theme Posts Using Jquery/Javascript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tumblr

Still on the same project.

I currently have [a theme](http://featherystylesheets.tumblr.com) I'm working on for tumblr. It's incredibly image heavy, so my goal is to load the entire page one (or a few) times while still being able to go to the next page of posts with pagination. The native pagination requires the entire page to load in order to get to older posts. What I *believe* I'm trying to achieve is loading with ajax, like [this](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/demo.html)?

(Tumblr also does have an established script similar to this, infinite scrolling, which allows you to load more posts by scrolling to the bottom. That convinces me that this is possible, but unfortunately, as far as I know, not created yet.)

So, can anyone help me, if only it is to point me in the direction of an already established plugin somewhere? I've run into quite the problem since i know very little about scripting and nothing about ajax. I'm still quite new at this!

Again, [here](http://pastebin.com/UDbkqYhX) is the entire code of the theme currently, if that will help you with your answer. (Obviously, my posts render in the "POSTSGOHERE" div.) And, just in case, [here](http://static.tumblr.com/q0etgkr/EIBmz7s0p/infinitescrolling.js#_=_) is the script for infinite scrolling that definitely works on tumblr.

(No one point out how I haven't chained all my plugins yet, I'm a little cautious since they currently *work* and I don't want to break anything!)

Thanks again, stackoverflow.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I *don't* want infinite scrolling. I want pagination via ajax, like in the example. Infinite scrolling also will slow down my page, since you can only load so many posts before it just harms the speediness of the theme. It's very cumbersome and messy for this page.

Also, guys, I can't comment on your replies, for some reason? I'll just edit up here in order to reply.

Comment: So you pretty much want to load the next page via ajax and replace the current one? Any specific reason to do that? Do you just need it for the pagination (1/2/3/4…) of the homepage or for any page like on [here](http://mikehacks.tumblr.com/tagged/blueprint)?

Comment: Can we see what you have tried? I appreciate you shared the theme code, but it would be more helpful if we could just see the javascript you have created.

Comment: Hey I have worked on a theme which already had this function in built. The plugin is available here: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ I found a version of the script here: http://static.tumblr.com/hugxd2w/CXrmy0lgn/script.js if you search for infinite-scroll-button you can see the action associated with it (although I am sure the source url will be much more helpful. This is the theme that contains it although it is premium http://www.pixelunion.net/themes/tumblr/expo/